# Why a real Vector Space has either one or infinitely many vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a hard time understanding the above question, so could someone help?

Comment: Is this something you're wondering on your own, something you're being asked to prove as homework, or what? Please provide some more context for which kind of confusion you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that every real vector space has infinitely many vectors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153860/prove-that-every-real-vector-space-has-infinitely-many-vectors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $v \in V$ is a vector in the vector space, then for every $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ also $\lambda v \in V$ (This is an axiom)

So either is $v = 0$ is the only vector in the vector space,  so all the vectors in the form $\lambda v$ are equal to $0$, or there are infinitel many, depending on $\lambda$

What I mean is: if for example $v = (1,1)$ is in out space, then also $2v = (2,2)$ has to be in the vector space (because of our axiom). But then also $3v = (3,3)$ and so on, for every $\lambda$: $(\lambda, \lambda)$ has to be in $V$

Comment: That is very well, but it may not be clear to the OP that $\lambda_1v$ and $\lambda_2 v$ are necessarily _different_ elements of the vector space. (And since this is not true for a module over an arbitrary ring -- which has the same axioms as a vector space except for what the scalars are -- a valid argument _has_ to depend on properties of $\mathbb R$ that arbitrary rings don't have).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am not sure I understand what you mean.. I added another line, do you think it's better?

Comment: x @Ant: Not really -- you're showing as an example that $\mathbb R^2$ in particular has infinitely many elements, but the question seems to be about an _arbitrary_ vector space. How do you know that different values of $\lambda$ always lead to different results of the multiplication $\lambda v$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah okay, I've seen your edit. So basically it should be proved that $\lambda_1 v \neq \lambda_2 v \iff \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ given that $v \neq 0$. To be honest though I would not be able to pinpoint the exact properties needed to show it (I guess that showing that every scalar different than $0$ in our field $\mathbb K$  has a unique multiplicative inverse, and unique inverse with respect to summation. I am not sure on the name of those properties though)

Comment: Yes. Something like: If $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$, then the distributive law (etc.) proves that $\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}(\lambda_1v-\lambda_2v)=v$, and if additionally $v\ne \vec0$ this requires that $\lambda_1v-\lambda_2v\ne \vec0$ -- at least once we know that $\lambda\vec 0=\vec 0$ for all $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^2$ is a good example of vector space. It's a plane. if you draw two axes: $x$ and $y$ you get an $\mathbb{R}^2$ space. You can have infinitely many points in this space.

For example the vector $v=(1,1)$. Also by definition of vector space any multiplication of $v$ lies in the vector space. In our case it's any point lying on the line defined by the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. E.g.: $(2,2)$, $(\pi,\pi)$, $(10^{100},10^{100})$...

Answer (score 1):

If you real vector $E$ space is no $\{0\},$ then it contains a vector $x\in E\setminus\{0\}.$ So you can consider the (no $\{0\}$) subspace $\mathbb{R} x=\{\lambda\cdot x\,;\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}.$ Note that it is a  $1-$dimensional vector space and then you can make an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}x$ and $\mathbb{R}^1=\mathbb{R}.$ In particular, it is a bijection and, as $\mathbb{R}$ has an infinity of elements, it is the case for $E$ too.